# How to find active and expired users, compare dates in Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
Tablename :- userinfo
Column :- expiration [ type:- text ]
Date format :- date('d M Y')
Database :- MySQL
Tech :- Codeigniter 3
```

Table contains record of users and I want to filter result through expiration date.

```
Active users :- $exp_date > $cur_date;
Expired users :- $exp_date < $cur_date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OR` to get the "Unlimited" value:

```
<?php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('userinfo');
$this->db->where('expiration <', $cur_date); // for expired users
                 OR
$this->db->where('expiration >', $cur_date); // for active users
$this->db->or_where('expiration', $unlimited_value); // or_where
?>
```

Comment: function getactiveusers() {
      $this->db->where('expiration >', date('d M Y'));
      $this->db->or_where('expiration', 'Unlimited');      
      $query = $this->db->get('userinfo');
      return $query->result();
      }

Comment: I'm using this function but it returns all users.. Can you solve it back @pathik

Comment: @VikramSoni save `date('d M Y')` this in one variable and then use that variable in query

Comment: I tried to store date in new variable and put that into query.. But it is showing all records..

Comment: run `$this->db->last_query()` and see the query

Comment: It is not working @Pathik.. I don't understand why ?

Comment: did you get the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('expiration <', $cur_date);
```

or

```
$this->db->where('expiration >', $cur_date);
```

Comment: Can we add OR clause here like expiration < $cur_date or expiration = Unlimited.

Comment: @VikramSoni what do you mean by "unlimited"

Comment: @VikramSoni what is the column to check "Unlimited"

Comment: @VikramSoni check my answer